# Получение данных из MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, mysqli

Здравствуйте.
Имеется таблица `table` со столбиками `id` `name` `model` `price` `warranty`, и имеется массив, допустим `$ids` (в котором находятся определенные `id` с таблицы `table`).
Как мне послать запрос с массивом `$ids`, что-бы вывести в массиве данные ячеек `price` и `warranty`?

P.S.S. Рабочий вариант:

```html
$query_price = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `price` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN (".implode(',', $ids).")");
$query_warranty = mysqli_query($CONNECT, "SELECT `warranty` FROM `prices` WHERE `id` IN (".implode(',', $ids).")");
$prices1 = [];
$warranty2 = [];
while ($result_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_price)) {
  $prices1[] = $result_price['price'];
}
while ($result_warranty = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_warranty)) {
  $warranty2[] = $result_warranty['warranty'];
}
$prices11 = implode(', ', $prices1);
$warranty22 = implode(', ', $warranty2);
echo $prices11.'</br>';
echo $warranty22;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ids = ['1','2','3','4'];

$query = "SELECT price, warr FROM table WHERE id IN (" . implode(",", $ids) . ")";

// если необходимо далее работать с массивом результата запроса
$rows = [];
while ($result_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_price)) {
    $rows[] = $result_price;
}
```

Comment: и потом выводить просто как $price и $warr ?

Comment: http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=010

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: а как мне вывести в массиве данные с ячеек `price` и `warr`? Не могу никак понять

Comment: точнее, вывести данные в виде массива

Comment: выводит только последнее значение

Comment: В самом вопросе я продемонстрировал как делаю запрос

Comment: Вы объясните, как хотите использовать результат запроса, я так нифига не понял. Вы в цикле while и так обрабатываете данные как элементы массива, только получаете один ряд результата за одну итерацию цикла. Вот у вас и получается что вы затираете всё  поседующей записью и на выходе переменная несёт последнюю запись

Comment: Мне надо будет потом в определенную таблицу, в определенную ячейку записать через запятую эти числа, которые получаю с ячеек ‘price’

Comment: В ответе дописал. пробуйте

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо огромное, буду пробовать)

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо.